# Use of compare() function in XPATH

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, predicate

I have a javascript function which modifies an XSLT stylesheet depending on values put into an HTML form.

The xml file this applies to has elements `<film>` with child element `<title>`, and I would like to apply templates to all films with a title alphabetically greater than the user input string.

In the javascript function, I have something like

```
...
var xmlDoc = getXMLdom("films.xml");
var stylesheet = getXML("stylesheet.xsl");

var userInput = document.inputForm.inputField.value;
var queryString = "film[compare(title, '" + userInput + "')>0]"

$(stylesheet).find("xsl\\:apply-templates, apply-templates").first().attr("select",queryString);
            if (typeof (XSLTProcessor) != "undefined") {
                var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
                processor.importStylesheet(stylesheet);
                var result = processor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
                document.getElementById("myTarget").appendChild(result);
            } else {
                window.alert("Your browser does not support the XSLTProcessor object");
            }
...
```

where `myTarget` is the id of a `<div>` element in my html page

queryString is then put into the stylesheet by the javascript function, so that I have the line

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="film[compare(title,'userInputStringValue')>0]"/>
```

But this is not working when I run it.

I have tried using functions without the user input, like

```
string-length(title)>7
```

and this works as expected.

Any ideas where I messed up? I am new to all this, so it may be something quite trivial

Comment: How in the world is the JavaScript involved in this? Please show how you are applying it.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear, I have added in some extra lines to the javascript section which hopefully clears up what is going on

Comment: As I understand it, most (all?) browser implementations of XSLT are still XSLT 1.0, and `compare` is an XPath 2.0 function.

Comment: @Ian Roberts: Thank you, it looks like you are right, which would explain the problem. I suppose the question now becomes: how can I achieve the same result using something supported by browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compare` function is XPath 2.0, and browser implementations of XSLT generally only support 1.0.

I don't think there's a cross-browser way to do what you want in XSLT 1.0 because there's no `compare` function, and the `<` and `>` comparison operators only compare numeric values, not arbitrary strings.  You may do better by manipulating the `xmlDoc` DOM in JavaScript to remove the `film` elements you're *not* interested in before you pass the DOM to the stylesheet, and then just have the stylesheet process all the (remaining) elements.  For example (untested, I'm not a JS expert):

```
$(xmlDoc).find('film').filter(function() {
  return ($(this).find('title').textContent <= userInput);
}).remove();
```

Comment: @Tomalak it does... in XPath 2.0.

Comment: Take a look into Saxon CE. It will be the only way to integrate it with XSLT and XPath 2.0 into the browser http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml